# Why can I add comments on Stack Overflow sometimes, but not others?

Tags: support, comments

Every now and then I cannot add comments to questions on Stack Overflow. Clicking on "Add comment" simply does nothing.

Then some time later it suddenly starts working again with the same browser, same computer (and of course the same user account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a client side (JavaScript or browser) problem. You could either not be loading the page all the way, or you might be disabling or altering JavaScript in someway.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but the page is loaded properly and I have not disabled JavaScript (and as I said: most of the times it starts working again after a couple of browser restarts)

Comment: @a_horse: Again, this sounds like a client side issue then. What would you have the site's devs do about it?

Comment: I thought it might be something "initiated" by Stackoverflow, e.g. disabling it because of traffic or some other reasons. But if you are certain it must be someting on my side, it's OK for me

Comment: I agree. This happens with some frequency to me, and it's always the browser's fault.

Comment: Just now for me, on the same computer, same browser window, different tabs,the 'comments' buttons, 'stackexchange' button and the expand control on the left of my user name on the top bar are working on meta.stackoverflow but not on stackoverflow itself...

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this answer does **not** apply in the OP's specific case, but it could explain similar behavior for other users:

You haven't reached the ["leave comments" threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) of 50 rep yet. When you do see the comment link, it's because you're looking at one of your own posts, which you can always comment on regardless of rep.